# No animation in Fluid Simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I work in version 2.82. I have a problem with mantaflow fluid. At the stage of preparing the file, after setting the settings - I can not play the animation of the water. When I click play, time starts to run, but the animation of the water does not appear. A similar problem was with special mantaflow version 2.79. I did it on several different tutorials, the problem is always the same - there is no animation. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your FLOW object is fully inside of the DOMAIN Object.  If it is not, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is a bug that is fixable using this method:

1. Select the `Domain` object
2. Go to the `Physics` tab
3. Change the `Resolution Divisions` by 1 digit
4. Replay timeline from the beginning

No idea why this happens, but it does.[image]